# Why are pandas categories/bins written with an opening parenthesis but a closing bracket?

Tags: python, pandas, categories, parentheses, brackets

I came across the following on the pandas doc page for [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

> Discretize into three equal-sized bins.

```
>>> pd.cut(np.array([1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3]), 3)
... 
[(0.994, 3.0], (5.0, 7.0], (3.0, 5.0], (3.0, 5.0], (5.0, 7.0], ...
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.994, 3.0] < (3.0, 5.0] ...
```

Why are the returned categories opened with a parenthesis `(` but closed by a bracket `]`? Does this denominate a special object in Python? At first I thought it was a typo but my console gives the same result.

Comment: http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/07-solving-inequalities/03-interval-notation-01

Comment: This is more of a question on basic math than it is pandas.

Comment: The fact that a punctuation mark means something in (basic) math doesn't mean it automatically has the same meaning in Python or pandas. Anyway I wasn't familiar with interval notation at all, thanks for the colourful crash course @ayhan XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they denote [intervals](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/intervals.html), wherein interval notation dictates that:

- a square bracket is inclusive;
- a parentheses is exclusive.

If `a` is your result, you'll see that `a.categories` gives you a Pandas [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html).